# Delete not working for a listview

Tags: android

I'm trying to delete a row in the database using this code, but it doesn't work

```
public void deleteAccount(long ID) {
   database.delete(Database.TABLE_BAG_TAG, Database.BAGTAG_ID + "="
            + ID, null);
}
```

here is the code for the button's delete

```
Button dlt = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        dlt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                String phoneNumber = numbers.get(position);


                tracker.deleteAccount(Long.parseLong(phoneNumber));

                numbers.remove(phoneNumber);


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

here the table creation

```
//BagTag Table Column
public static final String BAGTAG_ID = "_id";
public static final String BAGTAG_NUMBER = "bagtag";

 //BagTag Table
static final String TABLE_BAG_TAG= "BagTag";
//Create BagTag Table
private static final String CREATE_BAG_TAG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_BAG_TAG + " (" +
        BAGTAG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + BAGTAG_NUMBER + " TEXT" + " );";
```

Comment: my fields on that table is only BAGTAG_ID and BAGTAG NUMBER only

Comment: Do you get any errors or message in the logs..can you verify that.

Comment: i used it on my phone when i click the x button for delete it goes away but when i return to that page its there again

Comment: i think the listview is not properly refreshing check the database itself to see if the record is still in the table

Answer (score 0):

That's how you do it:

```
public void deleteAccount(long ID) {
    String whereClause = Database.BAGTAG_ID + " = ? ";
    String[] whereArgs = { Long.toString(ID) };
    db.delete(Database.TABLE_BAG_TAG, whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: Try to enclose this code into try-catch block and you'll get an SQL error when executing the delete statement. This would help to figure out what the problem is. Also are you sure that 'Database.BAGTAG_ID' field contains phone numbers?